# Требуется ли запятая перед союзом "и"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, придаточное-предложение

Нужна ли запятая перед ***и*** в таком предложении?

> Он утверждает, что не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие(,) и еда помогает ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы.

Answer (score 1):

**Три грамматические** основы:

(1) *Он утверждает, /// **что** (2) (он) не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие // и (3) (**что**) еда помогает ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы.*

Три основы. Этот СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными. Запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше предложение является *сложным* (у него две грамматические основы, их я выделил жирным):

> **Он утверждает**, что не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие (,) и **еда помогает** ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы.

Грамматические основы нужно разделять запятыми, даже если между ними есть союз `и`. А запятая перед `что` разделяет однородные сказуемые, а не части сложного предложения.

Вывод:

> Ставьте запятую: Он утверждает, что не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие, и еда помогает ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы.

Comment: Зонтик, разве всегда нужно разделять грамматические основы, соединенные союзом ***и***? А союз ***что*** разве не вводит придаточное предложение?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец союз `что` разделяет ОЧП, а не две грамматические основы. И части сложного предложения (даже если они соединены союзом **и**) нужно разделять запятыми.

Comment: Ну тогда желаю Вам дальше расширять и углублять свои знания в языке (по крайней мере, о неполных предложениях Вы уже писали). Здóрово, что отвечаете на вопросы. Успехов!

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец А если к "но" отнести? Это логичнее: *не нуждается, но она доставляет удовольствие и помогает*. "*Что не нуждается в пище и еда помогает*" не очень стыкуется. В идеале "что" после "но" поставить для структурной связки.

Comment: Про союз НО у Розенталя сказано  в теме ССП, но для однородных придаточных тоже скорее верно: "Противительный союз, после которого или перед которым находятся два соединенных союзом и простых предложения, ОБЩИМ ЭЛЕМЕНТОМ не является, поэтому запятая перед и ставится".  old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133 Примеание к п.2

Comment: @Sharon Не тупите. Если он это утверждает, то никакой запятой быть не может (общий глагол "утверждает"). А с запятой отдельная информация, то есть не то, что он утверждает (*Он утверждает, что не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие. И еда помогает ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы*).

Comment: @Sharon А про общий "но" вам ответ давал, и очень старался, а вы уже и забыли.

Comment: @oleedd Мой комментарий относился не к тому, нужна ли запятая, а к утверждению Зонтика: "Грамматические основы нужно разделять запятыми, даже если между ними есть союз ***и***".

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна в обязательном порядке:

***Он утверждает**, что не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие, и `еда помогает` ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы*.

Две грамматические основы, как сказано выше, нужно разделить запятыми (первая выделена **полужирным**, а вторая — `кодом`).

Есть ещë одно доказательство запятой — есть придаточное, присоединяемое слюзом *что*, которое завершается перед *и*:

*Он утверждает`, что не нуждается в пище, но получает от неё удовольствие,` и еда помогает ему настроиться на нужный лад для медицинской работы*.

---

Вывод: запятую обязательно ставим.

Comment: В этом предложении три грамматические основы: он утверждает; он не нуждается, но получает; еда помогает.

Comment: @Sharon Ну, третья как раз в придаточном.

Comment: И что из этого следует?  Главное +  два однородных придаточных.  Союз ЧТО пропущен, но относится к обоим придаточным. Так ли это?